# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE axios, laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.4

this seems to be strange,

I am using Laravel, VueJs and Axios for ajax requests.

Problem is few requests work well and few don't

[image]

here industry is working...

and country request is not working

[image]

Comment: Is country perhaps a post request (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf)? We need more details :) Maybe you exceed the max query string limit?

Comment: axios.get('/api/country').then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    if(!response.data.error){
                        this.$store.commit('setCountries',response.data.data);
                    }
                });

Comment: try{
            $countries = Country::all();
            return response()->json($this->successResponse($countries,''));
        }catch (\Exception $exception){
            return response()->json($exception->getMessage());
        }

Comment: How about trying to make the request with postman first?

Comment: few are working fine and only few are giving this error. ill try with postman

Comment: I tried, but no response

Comment: Then check your routes carefully and also your controller. Better yet: post them here!